# Ruby on Rails -> Create div dynamically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I work on a task manager app, and I want to create html div 'cards' (with title, duration etc...), with all the datas I got on a database in rails.

I guess that I have to use javascript functions, but I can't get a way to do it.
I saw a lot of things on google, but I can't find exactly javascript calls from a rails controller (because I only catch all datas in the controller).

Here is my controller :

```
def new
  # Retrieve all tasks in the project
  @taskModel = Task.new()
  @projectTasks = @taskModel.getProjectTasks()
  # Add tasks on html
  (0..@projectTasks.length).each do |i|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :js => "window.createTask();" } # I need to pass parameters in the createTask function
    end
  end
end
```

and my js file :

```
window.createTask = (title, content, duration) ->
  card = document.createElement('div');
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].appendChild(card);
```

With my code, I get this error : `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Comment: are you using angular? why do you **have to use javascript functions**.

Comment: I only use ruby on rails, I just need javascript to create html elements dynamically.

Comment: I precise that I can't load my js file in the html, because I download db datas with rails first, and then I need to create html tags with it.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionController::UnknownFormat` indicated that your ajax request is interpreted as a request with the wrong format. To answer this part better you'd have to post the javascript with the ajax call.

Secondly, you have to rethink the `render` in this block

```
(0..@projectTasks.length).each do |i|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :js => "window.createTask();" } # I need to pass parameters in the createTask function
    end
  end
```

You are calling `respond_to` multiple times which is just wrong. Put this loop into a `new.js.erb` view.